# unignore a thread / subthread in thunderbird

Tags: thunderbird

As per [this query](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/questions/1114343) at mozilla, I accidentally hit some keys and a stop sign, circle with a red line through it, appeared next to y user and I then could no longer see any emails arriving from him with thunderbird.

The solution provided [here](https://support.mozilla.org/en-US/kb/ignore-threads) to unignore the thread has not worked.

With Thunderbird 91.5.0 there is no `ignore threads` option in the `view` menu.

There are `ignore thread`, `ignore subthread` and `watch subthread` however in the `Message` menu.

I can find the hidden message with `CTRL-SHIFT-F` and can see under the message menu for that message that ignore thread is selected, but watch subthread is greyed out and clicking on it does nothing.

Is this a bug? If not how do you undo ignore thread?

Comment: The `Ignored Threads` option should be in the `Threads` submenu of the `View` menu rather than directly in the `View` menu. Is there no `Threads` item in your `View` menu?

Comment: @DavidYockey there is sorry about that, I should probably delete this question. I missed it the other day in my German Thunderbird 'Themen'. Will delete soon, all working now.

Comment: Glad you found it. :)

Answer (score 0):

With <kbd>k</kbd> or <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd> you toggle "ignore thread" from `set` to `unset`.

What worked for me:

- Find the message with stop sign with the finder (search box or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd>)
- Press <kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>k</kbd>

And the block sign on the message disappeared.